# Monaca Localkitで設定の取得に失敗する

Tags: monaca

お世話になっています。

Monaca Localkitにて、ビルド設定画面を開くと以下の画像のようなエラーが発生してしまいます。
この状態になるとJS/CSSコンポーネントが追加できなくなり、非常に困ったことになります。
同様の現象が発生されている方はいらっしゃいますか？
[image: screenshot]

ローカルファイルのどこに設定が保存されているか分からなかったので、クラウド上から引っ張ってきている可能性がありますね。
念のため、`.monaca/project_info.json`の中身は以下です。

````json
```
{
    "plugins": [
        "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca",
        "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"
    ],
    "framework_version": "3.5",
    "xcode_version": "6",
    "cordova_version": "4.1",
    "plugin_settings": []
}
```
````